# What is the difference between 일, 하루 and 날?

Tags: meaning

Do both 일 and 하루 mean today and 날 means the next day or does it depend on context?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stolen from a HINative [Answer](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/94950)

> **일** as a word is a quantifier so we use it to say what day of the month it is.
>
> **하루** is 24 hours/a day.
>
> **날** is a noun that you'd use to describe a day or say what kind of a day is it. 생일날, 추운 날 etc.

Examples

> 너가 쉬는일에 보자 (x)
>
> 너가 쉬는날에 보자 (o)

--

> 그럼 20날에 볼래?(x)
>
> 그럼 20일에 볼래?(o)

--

> 그럼 그 일에 봐(x)
>
> 그럼 그 날에 봐(o)